# Invoking Windows "Update Driver Software" in batch file or VB code

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, batch, updates

I'm working on a program in visual basic and I'm looking to find a way to invoke the driver updating inside a batch file, or in VB code.

Currently you have to go to the device manager:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtPgg.png)

And manually right click, hit update driver, and browse for the drivers there.

Is there anyway I can have this all automated in a batch file? Giving a directory for each unknown driver to search for in? This already exists inside windows, so I assume it is most defiantly possible.

Thanks.

Comment: All DM does is invoke windows update to search for driver updates, then if there are any returns it matches those with the driver id's (PCI\VEN) you requested be updated, very interesting question to customize this. I suppose one could packet sniff outbound connections when you invoke this DM driver update to see what is actually happening.

Comment: All that being said, I cannot tell you how many times a driver from Windows update has borked my PC's. Especially video drivers.

Comment: Have you tried [Pnputil](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732377%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#BKMK_Anchor2)?

Comment: Pnputil looks promising, Is there any real/easy way to have it only add specific drivers that are required? Whatever way windows updates driver software is what I'm looking for

Comment: @kpjVideo No idea, I've never used it. I just came across it as a possibility to solve you issue.